# A proposition about finitely generated modules

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. I proved that there exists an exact sequence of finitely generated $A$-modules $0 \to N_d \to E_{d-1} \to E_{d-2} \to \cdots \to E_1 \to E_0 \to M \to 0$ with the $E_i$ free.

Now I have to prove that $N_d$ is projective.

I have some difficulties with this proposition. Can anyone help me please? It would be great to have some hints.

My idea is to prove that $Ext_A^1(N_d,N)=0$ for all $A$-modules $N$, but I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: [Hilbert's syzygy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem). You can just recursively keep building a free resolution in the usual way to do part a). Part b) is deeper, and you really need to use suitable properties of regular rings to get there. In other words, you need non-trivial commutative algebra to do this. My recollection ends with the Koszul complex, so cannot help you with this approach. Presumably regularity leads to some kind of an induction, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Also, what book is this from? Once we have a better idea of exactly what tools you have available, we'll have a better idea of how to help you

Comment: It is impossible to suggest anything if we don't know what the other proof is, and what you have done up to that point... I could write an answer that involves no commutative algebra at all, but if that is the proof you know itll be useless, for example

Comment: Please do not massively edit the question after an answer was given.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How would you do that with the Koszul Complex?

Comment: That is explained in the end of chapter VII of Hilton & Stammbach *A Course in Homological Algebra*.

Answer (score 2):

a) is a completely formal result that only uses the fact that $A$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated.

b) is indeed a deeper question, but here’s an elementary approach. A standard argument shows that we can replace $A$ with its localization at a maximal ideal $m$. Write $m=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ such that the $x_i$ are a basis for $m/m^2$.

Let $M_i$ be the kernel of $F_{i-1} \rightarrow F_{i-2}$ (for $1 \leq i \leq d$, with $F_{-1}=M$, so that we have $0 \rightarrow M_i \rightarrow F_{i-1} \rightarrow M_{i-1} \rightarrow 0$.

I claim that for all $1 \leq j \leq i \leq d$, the multiplication by $x_j$ on $M_i/(x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1})$ is injective (ie $(x_1,\ldots,x_i)$ is a *regular sequence* for $M_i$).

Let’s write $I_i$ for $(x_1,\ldots,x_i)$.

Note that as $A$ is regular, $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ is a regular sequence for $A$.

(If you don’t know that, when $A$ comes from a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field, the Nullstellensatz says that there is one system of parameters which is of the form $X_1-a_1,\ldots,X_d-a_d$, and it’s obviously a regular sequence in the localization. We just need one system of parameters which is regular.)

*Proof*: by induction. Assume $(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1})$ work for $M_{i-1}$ ($i \geq 1$).

Let $0 \leq j < i-1$ be such that $0 \rightarrow M_i/I_jM_i \rightarrow F_{i-1}/I_jF_{i-1} \rightarrow M_{i-1}/I_jM_{i-1} \rightarrow 0$ is exact. Then apply the snake lemma to the multiplication by $x_{j+1}$: it is injective on the middle term, because $F_{i-1}$ is free and $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ is a regular sequence, so is injective on the left term. By assumption, it is injective on the right term, so the sequence of cokernels is exact, that is

$0 \rightarrow M_i/I_{j+1}M_i \rightarrow F_{i-1}/I_{j+1}F_{i-1} \rightarrow M_{i-1}/I_{j+1}M_{i-1} \rightarrow 0$ is exact.

In other words, $(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1})$ is a regular sequence for $M_i$ and $M_i/I_{i-1}M_i$ embeds in a power of $A/I_{i-1}$. But the multiplication by $x_i$ is injective on $A/I_{i-1}$. QED.

It follows that $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ is a regular sequence for $M_d$.

I claim that this implies that $M_d$ is free. For this, we need a lemma.

*Lemma*: let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a local Noetherian ring $(A,m)$ and $x \in m$ be such that $x: A \oplus M \rightarrow A\oplus M$ is injective. If $M/xM$ is free over $A/xA$, then $M$ is free.

*Proof*: there is a surjection $s: A^r \rightarrow M/xM$ that reduces to an isomorphism $i: (A/xA)^r \rightarrow M/xM$. It lifts to a map $u: A^r \rightarrow M$. Then $M=xM+u(A^r)$ so by Nakayama $u$ is surjective.

Consider the morphism $(u,u,i)$ between the exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A^r \rightarrow A^r \rightarrow (A/xA)^r \rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/xM\rightarrow 0$ (the injection is multiplication by $x$).

Then the snake lemma tells us that the multiplication by $x$ is an isomorphism on $\ker{u}$, thus by Nakayama $\ker{u}=0$ so $u$ is an isomorphism.

*Proof that $M_d$ is free*: we show by descending induction on $0 \leq i \leq d$ that $M_d/I_iM_d$ is free over $A/I_i$. The case $i=d$ is clear. For the induction step, we use the lemma, along with the fact that $x_{i+1}$ is a regular element for $M_d/I_iM_d$ and for $A/I_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm reading and studying your proof. Why we can replace $A$ with a localization of $A$ in a maximal ideal?

Comment: That’s a formal argument: a finitely presented module $M$ over a ring $A$ is projective iff every $M_m$ is free over $A_m$, for all maximal ideals $m$ of $A$. That’s because, for any $A$-module $N$, we have an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N)_m\equiv \mathrm{Hom}_{A_m}(M_m,N_m)$.

Comment: Ok thanks. Another question: when you write $M_i/(x_1,\dots, x_j)$ you actually mean $M_i/(x_1,\dots, x_j)M_i$, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: "Let $0 \leq j < i-1$ be such that $0 \rightarrow M_i/I_jM_i \rightarrow F_{i-1}/I_jF_{i-1} \rightarrow M_{i-1}/I_jM_{i-1} \rightarrow 0$ is exact." Can you explain me in details why you can choose a $j$ such that this fact Is true, please?

Comment: Let’s call $P(i,j)$ the property that the sequence for $i$ and $0 \leq j < i$ is exact. It’s clear that $P(i,0)$ is always true. That paragraph shows that for all $i,j$, $P(i,j)$ and $P(i-1,k)$ for all $k$ imply $P(i,j+1)$. It follows that $P(i,j)$ holds for all $i,j$.